# Closure, recursion and settimeout - Empty arrays being logged

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, closures, settimeout

The following function is being called recursively with different values being passed for 'input' and a constant 'delay'. The value passed for 'input' is an array of objects. The strange behavior I am experiencing is, that while the first console.log logs each array individually the one in the settimeout logs multiple empty arrays and only the last array has actual values inside of it:

```
function setDelay(input, delay) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input)));
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input)))
  }, delay)
}
```

With my understanding of how closure works, I would have guessed that both should always be the same since the value is being passed to each function individually and then later on available at the unwinding process the same way it used to be available for the first call.

I also tried a variation of the code using try-catch but had the same result. Does somebody know where my understanding of closure is lacking details?

Edit: Here you can find the whole recursive implementation: https://jsbin.com/mijitawaku/edit?js,console

Comment: Using `shift`, `unshift` and `splice`, you mutate your arrays.  So although you clone the same item in both places, you do so when it's in different states.  You could fix this by returning new items without mutating in `mergeSort`.

Comment: Note that the reason posters are asked to include their code here, is that sometimes it's not clear what's relevant.  In this case, the important code was not shown on site and is stuck in an external resource (JSBin) where it might be altered or removed.  So next time, make sure you include anything likely to be involved in the actual question, and not just a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're logging the same array but its items change. If you want the items to always be the same, you need to copy the array. Since you're using `JSON.stringify` that's easy:

```
function setDelay(input, delay) {
  input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));
  console.log(input);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(input)
  }, delay)
}
```